# AWS Domain Name Email for SSL Cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, vps

I create a free VPS on Amazon using their EC2 services. Everything is running smoothly, however, I would like to get a valid SSL cert for my web server. To do so I am on the StartSSL website and for the confirmation email they ask my to chose betweens one of those three email addresses:

```
postmaster@ec2-my-ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
hostmaster@ec2-my-ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
webmaster@ec2-my-ip.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

The problem is I have no clue how to access those mailboxes and I cannot select an other email address on StartSSL for the confirmation email.

Any idea?

Comment: You can now get a free SSL cert from AWS if you use their ELB in front of your website. Probably cheaper, and easily managed in the AWS environment https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get a "real" SSL cert for a domain you do not own.  If this is just for your own testing, you can create a self-signed cert, but for a public-facing web site you will need a domain that you control.

Once that is set up, you have two options for free certs.  The first is to put your instance behind an Elastic Load Balancer, and use the AWS Certificate manager to issue a free cert.

The other option, if you want to terminate SSL on your instance, is to use Let's Encrypt to issue your cert.  Note that the AWS certificate can include multiple host names, or even a wild card, but can only be used on an ELB. They are good for one year. The Let's encrypt certs are limited to a single host name, and are only good for 90 days - the whole point being that once it is set up, it's each to automatically renew them.

Comment: I "kind of" own the domain. I have a static domain name-> when I enter my domain name in my browser I am redirected to my websites. Therefore, everything is great, the only problem is thatwhen I try generate a valid, trused certificate using StartSSL the email for the validation is an email address that I do not own. How to solve that? :/

Comment: No, you are using a host name in a domain that amazon controls.  You need to control the domain - either control email, or be listed in the registration records for the domain - in order to get a cert for it.  That's the whole point of a domain-validated cert:  if you can prove that you own the domain, you get the cert.

Comment: do you know how to do that with a free VPS? I really need to set up qn HTTPS serv with a trusted cert (from StartSSL).